# 0(3) : error C1013: function "main" is already defined at 0(4)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've google this a little bit and I can't figure out what is wrong. My shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec2 coord2d;
void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This shader I know works, but when I try to link the program I get:

```
glLinkProgram:Vertex info
-----------
0(3) : error C1013: function "main" is already defined at 0(4)
```

I've checked to make sure that the viles are getting into memory properly and what not. they compile just fine. it is the linking step that something goes wrong. I'm clueless as to what and I've been hitting my head on this for quite some time. any tips?

Edit:

Here is the code i use to create the shader. it gets all the way to the conditional, it actually completes execution entirely, but the log prints out what you saw above.

```
GLuint updateProg()
{
    prog = glCreateProgram();
    if (vs == 0 || fs == 0) return 0;
    glAttachShader(prog, vs);
    glAttachShader(prog, fs);
    int link_ok;
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
    if (!link_ok) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "glLinkProgram:");
        print_log(prog);
        return 0;
    }
    return prog;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C++, and poor style in C.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I guess it's a good thing that this is neither C++ nor C code.

Comment: Can you show your shader loading code? The code you use to load the shader to OpenGL so that it can compile and link it?

Comment: Where is the rest of it? The part where you build those shader objects?

Comment: It build just fine. I use the shader creation made here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02

Comment: @Narcolapser: Yes, but how do you *call* it? Show us the code you're actually using, not what you copied from. Not posting the requested code isn't going to help us help you. Being able to follow how `vs` and `fs` get created is *crucial*.

Answer (score 29):

The error sounds like you might be trying to link two copies of the shader?  Check the code for creating shader object(s), loading code into them, and linking them into the program object.  That is, double-check all the calls to glCreateShader, glShaderSource, glCreateProgram, and glAttachShader to make sure they make sense.

**edit**

You've added the code that calls glCreateProgram above, but not the code that calls glCreateShader.  Your error is consistent with accidentally (incorrectly) passing `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` to glCreateShader for the fragment shader.

Comment: No, Nicol Bolas already pointed out the problem. The thing is: The compiler silently predeclared a symbol `void main()`, i.e. the main function you write in a shader is the function definition, but doesn't declare. The OP wrote main in a way that clashes with the predeclared symbol, but compiler doen't tell "wrong signature", but spits out an error that means "symbol has already been declared, but with a different type".

Comment: picking my answer for me datenwolf? :p anyway. the loading code makes sense, i used this tutorial for create shader and shader source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02 I'll add my creat program and linking up yonder.

Comment: +1 to your edit. I had this issue while working through some openGL tutorials, and had done exactly what you said: `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` instead of `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER` for the `glCreateShader` call.

Answer (score 16):

I had this error today.
It happened because I copy/pasted too much code.
I called glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); for both my vertex and fragment shader.
They compiled just fine, but they wouldn't link, because they were both vertex shaders.

Comment: Thanks! I did the exact same thing.

Comment: Still happens in 2020!

Comment: damn! I did the exact same thing! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GLSL is not C or C++. `void` cannot be used as the only parameter, as in `void main(void)`. What you want is `void main()`.

The error is admittedly cryptic though.

Comment: I just tried, didn't work. the thing is these shaders I doubt are the problem. These are known working shaders. I used them in another program, a tutorial, and in fact rebuilding that one and using these exact shaders succeeds.